# Install exe in silent mode in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, installation, silent

I have an existing application in VB.NET where I have a requirement to install a freeware EXE which for an unattended system. I know the path from where I have to install.

Note: I only have to write code to execute that inside the current code base and cannot create a batch file for the same.

Till now I have tried the following steps:
I have used Shell command to execute the EXE file giving the additional argument like:

```
Shell("C:\MOVEit_Freely_Install.exe /q C:\yourlogfilename.log")

Shell("C:\MOVEit_Freely_Install.exe /s")

Shell("C:\MOVEit_Freely_Install.exe /silent")

Shell("C:\MOVEit_Freely_Install.exe /qb C:\yourlogfilename.log")
```

It just opens the installer where I have to click Next button and then it will get install (Which I don't want).

Can you please suggest anything about that.

Thanks,
Puneet

Answer (score 3):

from a normal cmd window execute the file like `c:\moveit_freely_install.exe /?` and it should tell you if there's a silent option.

alternately, if it wraps an .msi you may be able to get at that and use regular microsoft installer switches to make it quiet.  I use 7zip to extract the exe contents in these cases.  if you have 7zip, right click the file and choose 7zip -> extract.

if you do find an msi, here are the interesting options for you:

```
`/q   n|b|r|f                                      Sets the UI level.

                                              q , qn - No UI.

                                              qb - Basic UI.

                                              qr - Reduced UI. A modal
                                              dialog box is displayed
                                              at the end of the
                                              installation.

                                              qf - Full UI. A modal
                                              dialog box is displayed
                                              at the end of the
                                              installation.

                                              qn+ - No UI. However, a 
                                              modal dialog box is
                                              displayed at the end of
                                              the installation.

                                              qb+ - Basic UI. A modal
                                              dialog box is displayed
                                              at the end of the 
                                              installation. If you 
                                              cancel the installation, 
                                              a modal dialog box is 
                                              not displayed.

                                              qb- - Basic UI with no
                                              modal dialog boxes. 
                                              The "/qb+-" switch
                                              is not a supported UI 
                                              level.`
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel I am trying for going with converting the file to MSI first and then I'll look into the solution that you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help:

```
Dim myProcess As New Process 
Dim param as String = "/?"
myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden 
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True 
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = ("moveit_freely_install.exe" & param) 
myProcess.Start()
```

It loads your app with it's parameter but no window.